# How to code a query in postgres and show each record when price changes in a series of data

Tags: postgresql

[image]

Highlighted in yellow are the records that will be the result set.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY beast_bid_price ORDER BY posted DESC) rn
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Is it possible to have ( partition by best_bid_price, best_offer_price ) to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: @Rn3l Yes you can add that in `PARTITION BY` clause which you want to grouping